# How to pass variables in a get request without showing it in the url - nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I want to make a get request to render a page but I need to pass 2 variables to that page. How can I create a ajax request to do this without having the variables show up in my url such as var1=?var2=?.

```js
$.ajax({
  async: true,
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/profile',
  data: {
    'UID': currentUid,
    'Name': user_data.displayName
  },
  success: function (res) {}
})
```

I thought of creating a post request and passing the variables that way but then how do I render the page that I want to because my Post request doesn't fetch the page

Comment: You still can send a response back from the server in a post request which can be received in the success or complete handler of the ajax post request. If you return HTML for example you can inject the return data into a div or what ever is needed.

Comment: or you make a get request use hashed one-way / single use tokens for verification/validation of the user, etc..

Answer (score 2):

In express you should get the page using

```
app.post
```

instead of

```
app.get
```

If you do for example:

```
var express=require('express')
var app=express()
app.get('/profile')
```

Your app will not fetch the page using POST method. Only GET method.
This might be your issue.

More info:

- [App req.`METHOD()`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)